# How to run a TeamCity build only for tags?

Tags: teamcity, nuget, build-process

I have several projects that produce NuGet packages that I publish to an internal server. We're using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org), and using tags in our Git repository to control the version numbers.

I'm tagging like this:

```
git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "tagged"
```

And, during the TeamCity build, I run `git describe --long`, which produces an output like this:

```
v1.0.0-0-ge9c047d
```

The fourth number in the output is the number of commits after the tag. The `0` here means that no commits have been made since the tag. I use these first four numbers as the version number (and, incidentally, the entire string as the AssemblyInformationalVersion).

I have TeamCity package and publish a NuGet package, but here's where it gets sticky. I only want to publish tags, never commits after tags (because the version number in that case would be wrong, possibly VERY wrong).

I've tried setting the "branch specification" in the VCS root to "+:refs/tags/*", which causes all the tags to be built, but TeamCity also insists on building the "default branch" as well. If I set the "default branch" to something that doesn't exist, I get an error.

I've thought about ending the build early if a particular build isn't a tag, but I can't figure out how to do that without FAILING the build, which isn't what I want.

How do I cause one or more build steps to only run for new tags, and not regular commits?

Answer (score 16):

If you are using TeamCity 8.x, there is now support for [VCS branch triggers](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-BranchFilter), which would allow you to not run builds from the default branch.

Try this:

1. Leave the Branch Specification in the VCS Root as "+:refs/tags/*"
2. Change the VCS build trigger rules to:

   +:*

   -:<default>

This will filter out the default branch from the trigger and you won't need to cancel the build.

Comment: This is close, but clicking on the "Run" button still builds the default branch.

Comment: What is the intended behavior in that case?

Comment: Good question. I guess *something* would run, but in that case, I don't want anything deployed to the NuGet server, meaning, the final build step wouldn't execute. Ideally, the build wouldn't *fail*, just wouldn't result in the deployment of any artifacts.

Comment: And which commit should it run against? The latest tag? The latest commit?

Comment: Latest commit, I guess. Really, what would be ideal, is to have builds always run automatically, for master and all other branches, but only have the NuGet publish happen for tags.

Comment: That's perfectly feasible, by using dependent build configuration, and putting the appropriate tag trigger only on the Publish NuGet build config.

Comment: I tried by using a snapshot dependency and a VCS trigger filter, but that didn't work. Would you care to update your answer with a description on how to achieve that?

Comment: That would be what I would try anyway. And it is working for me, although I'm not filtering for tags, but for commit messages. Can you be more explicit regarding what didn't work? Was the problem that it didn't trigger the dependent build?

Comment: Yes, it didn't trigger the build.