# How to trigger a TeamCity project to deploy to a server

Tags: build, triggers, teamcity, jetbrains-ide, kanban

I am using TeamCity (version 9.1.5 if that matters) and I am trying to figure out how to create a trigger that deploys the project to a server. Or maybe there is a way to deploy a project to a server without using a trigger on TeamCity.

Comment: What do you want to trigger the build? And how is the project to be deployed, e.g. Octopus or something like that?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how the project is to be deployed. I am just doing it through TeamCity.

Comment: I don't think you've understood what I'm asking. What event do you want to trigger the deployment, should it happen at a particular time, after X build has completed, or something else? How do you deploy the build right now, manually copying files, xcopy, some build deployment software or scripts?

Comment: I want the deployment to be triggered when a commit is made after a build has been completed. And I want the build to start off when a trigger is triggered by a commit to the project (this part is already set up). Also, the build steps for the project source code is already set up on the TeamCity project as well.

Comment: So you've already got an example trigger to work from that's doing exactly what you need. Is the commit after the build to the same repo? Is it tagged or something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509113/how-to-run-a-teamcity-build-only-for-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very broad question, but I will share the approaches I have used in a couple of scenarios:

1) To deploy when a code checkin is performed, I have setup a build configuration that does the deployment, added the build configuration that does the compiling & packaging as a snapshot and artefact dependency which is then triggered with a Finish Build Trigger https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger

2) To deploy at a given time of the day but only when new code has been checked in, I have setup a build configuration as above but triggered with a Schedule Trigger https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers ensuring to select the dependent build in the **Build Changes** section.

With regards to how to perform the deployment there are many options, I have used WebDeploy for ASP.Net applications and MSI packages executed by Remote Powershell scripts for Windows Services, but other options are also available depending on the technology you have.

JetBrains provide an end to end example for ASP.Net in their on-line documentation, search for "Continuous Delivery to Windows Azure Web Sites (or IIS)"