# How to detect a tag for a current code change in TeamCity?

Tags: git, teamcity

I`m using Git as VCS in TeamCity.

I want to extract the `git tag` from the commit for which we are doing the build.
Any idea how I could do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but not natively.

You'll need to install git on your build agents and ensure that code is checked out on the agent. Further information as to why this needs to be done can be found in the [TeamCity Checkout Mode Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Mode)

[image]

This will ensure that a git repository is created on the agent and you can then run git commands natively. The one you'll need is

```
git describe --tags <commit-id>
```

In TeamCity you should be able to run a PowerShell step similar to this

[image]

This will error if there are no tags! You can add the `--always` switch to this is return a shorted hash if no tags exist.

**SET TEAMCITY VARIABLE**

```
$tag = git describe --tags %build.vcs.number% --always
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='MyParameterName' value='$tag']"
```

The parameter "MyParameterName" must already be defined.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! this is helpful ! But how I can put the output of the custom script execution into TeamCity ConfigutationParameter (or somewhere else) so that I could reuse the tag text? In my case I want to use tag for the nuget package version number ?

Comment: That seems a more precise answer than mine. +1

Comment: I created Configuration parameter named MyParameterName and then put the provided script into "Custom script" - build fails with the message "The syntax of the command is incorrect." :(

Comment: I've ammended this to a PowerShell script and confirmed it worked. Sorry about that.

Comment: Than you for the help guys, this is how it works for me:

Comment: $cmd = "git describe --exact-match --abbrev=0 --tags $commitHash --always" <br/>
$cmdFetch = "git fetch -t"

Invoke-Expression $cmdFetch
$tag = Invoke-Expression $cmd

Write-Host "##teamcity[message text='Commit hash for build is: %build.vcs.number%']"
Write-Host "##teamcity[message text='Version of upcoming nuget package is: $tag']"

Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='CurrentTag' value='$tag']"

Answer (score 0):

You can check the output of [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)

```
v1.0.4-14-g2414721
       ^^
```

If you don't see '0' after the tag, then the current commit is *not* referenced by a tag.

For getting all the tags ofr a current commit:

```
 git log -n1 --pretty=format:%h%d @
```

Don't forget you can have multiple tags associated to a commit.

---

But for TeamCity, check if you could use [VCS branch trigger](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-BranchFilter) which can help building only for tags with

- Branch Specification in the VCS Root as "+:refs/tags/*"
- VCS build trigger rules to: `+:*` and `-:<default>`.

(source: "[How to run a TeamCity build only for tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515660/6309)")

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as I understand this approach will work only for regular build. Sorry, probably I should have mentioned it in my question - I am interested in the Custom Build scenario - when you manually select the change for which you want to do a build. I could use GIT DESCRIBE to get the tag - but how I can get the commit identifier for which I want to do the build ?